# XCopy Skip Identical Files Only

Tags: xcopy

Is it possible to use xcopy to copy files and only overwrite existing files that differ in size? I'd like to skip overwriting identical files to speed up my copy process. I don't see anything in the [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true).

Right now my call looks like `xcopy /s /e /y ...`

Comment: may be of interest http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy30.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XCopy cannot do that, but [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) ("Robust File Copy for Windows") can.

Comment: I was able to easily swap out xcopy for Robocopy, and its performance is awesome. Thanks!